# Remove single Object from realm.io android if it still exists

Tags: android, realm, race-condition

I use realm to store items later shown in a ListView.
The items have a delete button and if the user clicks that button two times, the app crashes, because realm says the object is no longer valid to operate on. Is there a more elegant solution than to just try and catch that exception and ignoring it?

Here is  the code of the onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Timer " + timer.getUUID() + " was stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmResults<Timer> result = realm.where(Timer.class).equalTo("uuid", timer.getUUID()).findAll();
    result.deleteAllFromRealm();
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Try to check `if(result.size() > 0){ // delete all from realm}`  before `result.deleteAllFromRealm();`.

Comment: that is not the problem, I already have a reference to that object, and when I try to get the UUID to be able to delete it, that is the point where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Delete the item from the listview? so the user can't click delete

Comment: That won't be possible either, since the listview uses another realmresult list as a backend and i can't remove an object from that list. found another solution anyway, i'll post an answer now :D

Comment: So typical that as soon as I ask a question, I find the answer myself in minutes, but not in the days before, where I've looked multiple times into it already :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that since I already had a reference to that object, I could use realms isValid() method, see my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
        if (timer.isValid()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Timer " + timer.getUUID() + " was stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            timer.deleteFromRealm();
        }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

I also found the deleteFromRealm() Method on RealmObject, that I could not find earlier for some reason..
So, the correct solution should be:

```
RealmObject o = someRealmObject;
realm.beginTransaction();
if (o.isValid()) o.deleteFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();
```